# how to check for "command invoker error" in python 2.6

Tags: python

I have a python 2.6 script that I'd like to have it do some simple error checking.  if the incorrect item is entered the below error will come up in the traceback.  I'd like to pop up a GUI using Easygui when this occurs, but I'm at a loss as to how to do this.

> CommandInvokerError: The server dudley could not fulfill the request. HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Catch the `CommandInvokerError` exception around whichever calls can cause it: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: Put your code in a `try` block and have the EasyGUI code in an `except CommandInvokerError:` block.

Comment: If millimoose's comment isn't sufficient for you, you will have to show us [stripped down actual code](http://sscce.org), and also tell us what library you're using that generates that `CommandInvokerError` (since it isn't anything in the stdlib, and I don't think it's in EasyGui either).